# Prevent AWS root to access running EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am selling a software that runs on EC2 instances. It creates an instances, performs the job and terminates.

A client is interested in my software but he needs to run it in his AWS environment.

Is there a way I can prevent anyone to connect SSH, web terminal, etc. to the running EC2 instance?
(The instance must be connected to internet and will be in a VPC)

I have read that I can disable Session Manager.

Thanks

Comment: Will your customers be ok with having a machine in their VPC that they have no visibility into?  Depending on how you create the instance you can turn off SSH totally but that means it's off for everyone.  Otherwise you could create a user with a PEM key that you don't share with the customer.  But if I was your customer I'd have to trust your software quite a bit to allow it into my VPC.

Comment: Why not put it in your _own_ AWS Account, and then grant appropriate access to it (eg use VPC Peering to allow access from their systems)?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I am not sure how the final topology will be. Maybe I end up running it in my own aws. But I would like to have good reasons to one or other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Other than running this on AWS account customer does not have access to, it will be very tricky to accomplish this.

Even when you create an instance without keys, or do not handle keys to the customer, they will be able (given sufficient permissions), to create AMI from that server and choose different key during provisioning.

Comment: This is very interesting, because it is true a root user could create an image and then run another instance and inspect the contents...

Comment: It does not need to be a root user. Any IAM / SSO user with sufficient EC2 permissions.